# How to store new items in an array each time a component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to store 10 items in an array each time the component is rendered. 10 items must be stored starting from index 0 to 9 and then those items must be deleted and next ten items must be stored so that I can map over the data I am receiving from my api.

I tried chaining a filter with the map but it only works on the first 10 items.

```
    //Update
    const CollectionPreview = ({title,movieItems}) =>  {
     const index = React.useRef(0)
     const movieData = movieItems.slice(index.current, index.current + 10)
     index.current += 10
    return (
        <div className="collection-preview">
            <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
              <div className="preview"> 
                {console.log(movieData)}
              </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: So in other words: you receive a large amount of records fron the API, and you only want to show 10 of them with some kind of pagination?

Comment: Check this https://arjunphp.com/can-paginate-array-objects-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, you would not want to edit external data in-place. You could use the hook useRef() to keep a counter of which items to display next, and increment the counter on each render. The items can be fetched from the movieItems array using slice(), which will not modify the original array.

```
function MyComponent() {
    const index = React.useRef(0)

    const movieData = movieItems.slice(index.current, index.current + 10)

    index.current += 10
}
```

Comment: That works but now I'm getting the same 10 elements everytime, any reason why the counter is not updating on re render?

Comment: Please check the update and let me know what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Is your component re-mounting as well? States and refs are not carried over when a component re-mounts.

Comment: I'm just mapping it over in another component

CollectionData.map(items => <CollectionPreview key={items.id} title={items.title} />)

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. Unable to try it myself right now, but I think it might a problem somewhere else. For instance if the parent component re-mounts the children will re-mount as well.

Comment: The parent component only mounts once, I haven't been able to figure this out yet, tried all day but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is just using the Array.splice method detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var top10 = arr.splice(0 ,10);

console.log(arr); //[11, 12]
console.log(top10); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```